# pragma omp for simd does not generate vector instructions in GCC

Tags: c, gcc, openmp, vectorization, simd

**Short**: Does the `pragma omp for simd` OpenMP directive generate code that uses SIMD registers?

**Longer**:
As stated in the [OpenMP documentation](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpsu42.html#x65-1470002.9.3.2) "*The worksharing-loop SIMD construct specifies that the iterations of one or more associated loops will be distributed across threads that already exist [..] using SIMD instructions*". From this statement, I would expect the following code (simd.c) to use `XMM`, `YMM` or `ZMM` registers when compiling running `gcc simd.c -o simd -fopenmp` but it does not.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 100

int main() {
    int x[N];
    int y[N];
    int z[N];
    int i;
    int sum;

    for(i=0; i < N; i++) {
        x[i] = i;
        y[i] = i;
    }

    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        #pragma omp for simd
        for(i=0; i < N; i++) {
            z[i] = x[i] + y[i];
        }
        #pragma omp for simd reduction(+:sum)
        for(i=0; i < N; i++) {
            sum += x[i];
        }
    }
    printf("%d %d\n",z[N/2], sum);

    return 0;
}
```

When checking the assembler generated running `gcc simd.c -S -fopenmp` no SIMD register is used.

I can use SIMD registers without OpenMP using the option `-O3` because according to [GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#index-O3)
it includes the `-ftree-vectorize` flag.

- `XMM` registers: `gcc simd.c -o simd -O3`
- `YMM` registers: `gcc simd.c -o simd -O3 -march=skylake-avx512`
- `ZMM` registers: `gcc simd.c -o simd -O3 -march=skylake-avx512 -mprefer-vector-width=512`

However, using the flags `-march=skylake-avx512 -mprefer-vector-width=512` combined with `-fopenmp` does not generates SIMD instructions.

Therefore, I can easily vectorize my code with `-O3` without the `pragma omp for simd` but not for the other way around.

At this point, my purpose is not to generate SIMD instructions but to understand how do OpenMP SIMD directives work in GCC and how to generate SIMD instructions only with OpenMP (without `-O3`).

Comment: Adding the simd clause doesn't alter the cost algorithms of popular compilers.  Loop length 100 is barely enough to benefit from simd alone (not even avx512) in a simple reduction loop such as yours, and may not be enough to benefit from omp parallel in either loop.    omp for simd requires generation of something resembling nested loops.  Unless the compiler can specialize for a specific loop count which is a multiple of simd length times number of threads, both inner and outer loops require run-time remainder and possible alignment code.

Comment: The usual effect of simd clause with gnu compilers is simply to over-rule detection of possible aliasing which may invalidate simd vectorization.

Comment: @tim18: 100 elements is enough for 128-bit SIMD to be worth it on modern x86, especially when the size (multiple of the vector width) and alignment (by 16) are known good.  The time to horizontal-sum the vector at the end is pretty small.  Unlike some microarchitectures (e.g. some ARM) where the vector unit is only loosely coupled and there are big delays to get a vector result as scalar, x86 only has a couple cycle latency for `movd eax, xmm0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Enable at least `-O2` for `-fopenmp` to work, and for performance in general

> `gcc simd.c -S -fopenmp`

**GCC's default is `-O0`, anti-optimized for consistent debugging**.  It's never going to auto-vectorize with `-O0` because it's pointless when every `i` value from the C source has to exist in memory, and so on.  [Why does clang produce inefficient asm with -O0 (for this simple floating point sum)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53366394/why-does-clang-produce-inefficient-asm-with-o0-for-this-simple-floating-point)

Also impossible when you have to be able to single-step source lines one at a time, and even modify `i` or memory contents at runtime with the debugger, and have the program keep running like you'd expect the C abstract machine would.

**Building without *any* optimization is utter garbage for performance; it's insane to even consider if you care about performance enough to be using OpenMP.**  (Except of course for actual debugging.)  Often the speedup from anti-optimized to optimized scalar is more than what you could gain from vectorizing that scalar code, but both can be large factors so you definitely want optimizations beyond auto-vectorization.

---

> I can use SIMD registers without OpenMP using the option `-O3` because according to GCC documentation it includes the `-ftree-vectorize` flag.

Right, so do that.  `-O3 -march=native -flto` is usually your best bet for code that will run on the compile host.  Also `-fno-trapping-math -fno-math-errno` should be safe for everything and enable some better FP function inlining, even if you don't want `-ffast-math`.  Also preferably `-fprofile-generate` / `-fprofile-use` profile-guided optimization (PGO), to unroll hot loops and choose branchy vs. branchless appropriately, etc.

`#pragma omp parallel` is still effective at `-O3 -fopenmp` - GCC doesn't enable autoparallelization by default.

Also, `#pragma omp simd` will use a different vectorization style sometimes.  In your case, it seems to make GCC forget that it knows the arrays are 16-byte aligned, and use `movdqu` loads (when AVX isn't available for an unaligned memory source operand for `paddd xmm0, [rax]`).  Compare https://godbolt.org/z/8q8Dqm - the `main._omp_fn.0:` helper function that `main` calls doesn't assume alignment.  (Although maybe it can't after division by number of threads splits up the array into ranges, if GCC doesn't bother to do vector-sized chunks?)

---

### Use `-O2 -fopenmp` to get what you were expecting

OpenMP will let gcc vectorize more easily or efficiently for loops where you didn't use `restrict` on pointer args to functions to let it know that arrays don't overlap, or for floating point to let it pretend that FP math is associative even if you didn't use `-ffast-math`.

**Or if you enable some optimization but not full optimization** (e.g. `-O2` which doesn't include `-ftree-vectorize`), **then `#pragma omp` will work the way you expected.**

Note that the `x[i] = y[i] = i;` init loop doesn't get auto-vectorized at `-O2`, but the `#pragma` loops are.  And that without `-fopenmp`, pure scalar.  [Godbolt compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tQVvQAZPLUwA5YwCNMxLgDZSAB1QLC62nsMTQS8fNTorG3sjJxdOdyUVMNoGAmZiAgDjU05FZUxVPxS0ggi7R2cuHIVU9MygqpqS6zLois5OAEpFVANiZA4AcikAZmtkQywAanFhnWr8VAA6BBnscQAGAEERrCpmydtJznX1je2t6wJJo2ZrCA7pgHZZLcm3ycvJgA9xAFZpWx/AAiMxem3eH3okwAnn8AcDQWcIZ8AF5wwG/EHDMHIqF4RGvd6fBTGAnncHvGjECD44ZA07Yj7TWYHUEfORyB7iZ5IiHvH7/fGY5lA9nY3l8mFwoWimai2k497ckFbCXTSTDDzEZjAG6TVBGDyTDxpNjsVhq7mKyUjLU6vUGo1UyY%2BIzoNUQqk0uUM6RMmY6VmM/EyTlPa2S95owXAkXfaWxuRSmOYsmRp4qik2jV23XMfWGybO13oSbETDoAwFOgQOQgElGDoeykkb1033%2BlmA4McmRcnmE9NvBvq2R0%2BMprERiHKy2PTMQrWXKi1ySSKS/Usb92/HS0KSSUjRgEAenXmNILuMTfFqsHZcwBF6tEmvrOyoGXVYIAGvwGpFMAZ1n/VAfx0Xs/QUHo%2BkwdVhk4f8CB/YCOi6ABrEBhmGRZOAADlcYZuG4VxOGGABOVwyN4b8Bm4f9AOA0hQIGf8FBAdZSCQoDP1IOBYCQNBDTwdgyAoCBBI8YSKmAMjhlIPZWAIZw2IgBxkP/BxrDSaEfwQ0hBKMLQCAAeVoVgdO40gsBuUR2HUqy8HLAoADdMDYyzMC%2BfIDCU3T/0uZR7NYPAHG1YhoT0LA/M44g8CMPyuhoegmDYDgeH4QRhFEFAIKEEK2MgLpUA8JJ3IAWi%2BZBJjK4zJGqmgPC0Q1WLyatTAgcw6myUhzFKKIYhAX4OJCXw6C64JvFG2g%2BvKFwhtyRJCkacaqlapIinSGbWhcbhD2qYoVsURotoG3auig3p%2Bi4L8fz/AD7OYr58LK1xuEmYBkCqsjFmGSYIFwQgSDgnJJj0ISROBh5wNDGREPU1DSAwrDFl%2BAiyNI9ZcIosj1lkoQfzo0h4uODiGJAn9WPYzj4d4mBEBQR0pNEygJKZkAZLkhSlOIFS1MszTaG06KDKM0zzPs6yRGAOzLPwJy1Fc9zGM87zfIGPSApoxjgtC7TIsGPSCFi%2BL1Z4pLGBYOz0oEQ8srEXKdYK%2B4mJKvxysq6rjN%2BsqGqajwWsWjQOu0Q7euafq2k8SakkOkakhOyOEnydblv0LJBCTtqNqaSJZoz1PAm6/bNvDvPOm6S60pu396Ien8ntcF63o%2Br6fr%2BgGiGIYHLzBySIZGSQoYguHuIRhBMGYLAXGdpHsMkbgyMeXbJAorCKMedwaMJsmmIpxQqa4lDq8kWvLOYkej9IVyeb8EBuCAA)

---

The serial `-O3` code will run faster for this small `N` because thread-startup overhead is nowhere near worth it.  But for large N, parallelization could help if a single core can't saturate memory bandwidth (e.g. on a Xeon, but most dual/quad-core desktop CPUs can almost saturate mem bandwidth with one core).  Or if your arrays are hot in cache on different cores.

Unfortunately(?) even GCC -O3 doesn't manage to do constant-propagation through your whole code and just print the result.  Or to fuse the `z[i] = x[i]+y[i]` loop with the `sum(x[])` loop.

Comment: Thank you. Even though I agree with you, -O2 is not part of the OpenMP API specifications and declaring "pragma omp for simd" should be enough to tell the compiler to generate SIMD instructions. One thing is the OpenMP specification and another the code optimizations performed by -O{1,2,3}. With you helpful answer I see that GCC may not follow the OpenMP API, maybe because they also make your assumption that "it is utter garbage for performance". I know that running without performance flags makes no sense, but here my point was not trying to run it faster, but to understand and learn.

Comment: @albertgumi: Different compilers call their optimization options different names so it makes sense that the spec doesn't mention any specific compiler options.  Some compilers default to enabling optimizations (like ICC used to).  It's assumed that if you enable optimization in any case where you care about the generated asm.  `#pragma omp simd` is a hint for the compiler that it should try to vectorize a loop but depending on the source it might not be able to.  From a certain PoV, `-O0` / debug mode even the most trivial loop too complex for the braindead compiler.

Comment: @albertgumi: I kind of understand your initial confusion that optimization wasn't enabled by default, but I don't think your argument that GCC should vectorize at `-O0` makes any sense.  It seems better to me to be able to single-step the scalar logic of a loop in debug mode, even if you used `#pragma omp simd` or `parallel`.  OpenMP is something that enables compilers to make better code if they want to; it doesn't *force* them. GCC doesn't vectorize at -O0 because that mode compiles each C statement to a separate block of asm, not because it's intentionally slow (that's a side effect)

Comment: I appreciate your well exposed answer. I think you are right.